# Выдает ошибку (IndexError: list index out of range на 18 строке) при попытке выбрать второй элемент строки из файла cvs

Tags: python, база-данных, список

```
import csv

list = []

with open('games.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    for row in reader:
        cond = int(row['white_rating']) - int(row['black_rating'])

        if -100 <= cond <= 100 and row['winner'] == 'white':
            move = str(row['moves'])
            move = move.split()[0]
            list.append(move)

        elif -100 <= cond <= 100 and row['winner'] == 'black':
            move = str(row['moves'])
            move = move.split()[1]
            list.append(move)


print(len(list))
```

CVS файл [здесь](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HkVhU_DL22OquSbvuhKUhbWHMVNE2Qek9Q88mKGKs_4/edit#gid=230018563).

Comment: Мы не имеем права доступа к вашему файлу, только вы.

Comment: Да. только заметил. Исправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что мы не имеем права доступа к вашему файлу, я могу только гадать:

```
move = str(row['moves'])
```

В переменной `move` будет строка, **в которой не находится ни один сепаратор** (пробел или табулятор).

Потому в последующей команде (на строке 18)

```
move = move.split()[1]
```

часть `move.split()` даст список *только с одним элементом* (его индекс `0`), а элемент с индексом `1` не существует.

---

*Допольнение:*

После получения доступа к вашему CSV-файлу это наверно так:

- В строке **13703** в столбце М (заголовок `moves`) находится только `d3`:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Я немножко переписал вашу программу,

- главным образом потому, что в ветвях `if` и `else` делаете практически то же самое, разница только в индексе (0 или 1),
- и добавил выявление ошибок:

```
import csv

list = []
WB_IDX = {'white': 0, 'black': 1}

with open('games.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    for i, row in enumerate(reader, start=2):                # i: номер строки
        cond = (int(row['white_rating']) 
              - int(row['black_rating']))
        winner = row['winner']

        if -100 <= cond <= 100 and winner in WB_IDX:
            move = row['moves']                              # не надо str()
            if ' ' not in move:
                print('*** Ошибка в строке №', i)
                continue                         # переход на следующую строку CSV-файла
            move = move.split()[WB_IDX[winner]]
            list += [move]

print(len(list))
```

---

*Вывод:*

> ```
> *** Ошибка в строке № 13703
> *** Ошибка в строке № 18585
> 8670
> ```

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил что доступ ограничен. Исправил

Comment: После получения доступа я дополнил мой ответ.